# SVM train and predict using OpenCvLib320 in Android

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio, svm, knn

I am using Android studio with OpenCV sdk 3.2 version.
I am trying to train using readymade API available for SVM

Part of my code retrieves the image from the internal memory of the phone, and helps to train using SVM

```
    File mnist_images_file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream images_reader = new FileInputStream(mnist_images_file);

    Mat training_images = null;
    try {
        ...
        training_images = new Mat(total_images, px_count, CvType.CV_8U);
        for (int i = 0; i < total_images; i++) {
            byte[] image = new byte[px_count];
            images_reader.read(image, 0, px_count);
            training_images.put(i, 0, image);
        }
        training_images.convertTo(training_images,
                CvType.CV_32FC1);
        //Read Labels
        Mat training_labels = null;
        byte[] labels_data = new byte[total_images];

        File mnist_labels_file = new File(labels_path);
        FileInputStream labels_reader = new
                FileInputStream(mnist_labels_file);

        try{
            training_labels = new Mat(total_images, 1,
                    CvType.CV_8U);
            Mat temp_labels = new Mat(1, total_images,
                    CvType.CV_8U);
            header = new byte[8];
            //Read the header
            labels_reader.read(header, 0, 8);

            //Read all the labels at once
            labels_reader.read(labels_data,0,total_images);
            temp_labels.put(0,0, labels_data);

            //Take a transpose of the image
            Core.transpose(temp_labels, training_labels);
            training_labels.convertTo(training_labels,
                    CvType.CV_32FC1);
            labels_reader.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.i("MNIST Read Error:", "" + e.getMessage());
        }

        images_reader.close();

        SVM svm = SVM.create();
        svm.setType(SVM.C_SVC);
        svm.setKernel(SVM.POLY);
        svm.setGamma(3);
        svm.train(training_images, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE,training_labels);
```

I am trying to train using available dataset that is already present in the device in the form of images . but calling this train() gives me the following error:

03-01 17:10:24.359 12035-12035/com.example.vankit.knnexample E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The kernel parameter  must be positive) in void cv::ml::SVMImpl::checkParams(), file /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1302
03-01 17:10:24.361 12035-12035/com.example.vankit.knnexample E/org.opencv.ml: ml::train_10() caught cv::Exception: /home/maksim/workspace/android-pack/opencv/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp:1302: error: (-211) The kernel parameter  must be positive in function void cv::ml::SVMImpl::checkParams()
03-01 17:10:24.362 12035-12035/com.example.vankit.knnexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Could you please suggest a way out for this?

Comment: I am implementing this in JAVA

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this problem is still current, but as far as I know SVM module in newest version of OpenCV (I mean 3.0+) is not working perfectly while using other kernel than LINEAR. Try maybe using linear kernel, or changing version of opencv to 2.4.13.2 (newest of 2+) and see if you encounter any problems.

P.S. I would comment but due to my reputation I can't do that...